# Distribution of difference of points in same tail of normal curve?

Tags: probability-distributions

If $x$ and $y$ are random values drawn from the part of a normal curve that is greater than a fixed $C$.  The distributions of $x$ and $y$ are clearly not normal, but is the distribution of their difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $x$ and $y$ are independent, otherwise the question is underspecified.

The answer is no. [Cramér's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem#Normal_random_variables) implies that if two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not both normal, their difference (being the sum of $X$ and $-Y$, which are also independent) cannot be normal.

Anyway, I used Mathematica to compute the distribution of $Z=X-Y$ for a standard normal distribution and $c=0$; it's
$$f(z)=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}e^{-|z|^2/4} \left(1-\operatorname{erf}\frac{|z|}2\right)$$
and looks like this:

[image]